# Unsure of how to re-render page using parent state and child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an event handler to re-render a whole other component upon being clicked but can't figure out how to pass it to the child component and get it to actually work.

I've tried passing the event handler in different ways and by writing the App component as a function with hooks too.

App.js:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      clicked: true,
    })
  }

  renderLoad(handleClick) {
    return <Load handle={() => handleClick}/>
  }

  renderQuiz () {
    return <Quiz />
  }

  render () {
    return (
    <div className='main'>
    {this.state.clicked ? this.renderQuiz() : this.renderLoad()}
    </div>
```

Load.js

```
function Load(props) {
    return <button onClick={() => props.handle}>Let's get started</button>
}
```

The App component should render the Quiz based on the state being true after the button is clicked.

Comment: Why do you want to re-render? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

you are pretty close!

Something to note, when referring to functions in the same component, use this.myFunction. No need for the anonymous function call () =>.

So:

```
//doesn't work
<Load handle={() => handleClick}/>

//works
<Load handle={this.handleClick}/>

//doesn't work
onClick={() => props.handle}

//works
onClick={props.handle}
```

Here's a working sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-wildflower-l2ll5

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely clears up the confusion I had about how to reference functions.

Comment: You can accept this as the solution and upvote so others may find it more easily.